Is an autonomous ODE equivalent to time-invariant ODE?
In general, an ODE $$\dot x = f(x,t)$$ is called autonomous if $$f(x,t) = g(x)$$ for some $g$.
An ODE is called linear time-invariant (LTI) if it can be put in the form $$\sum k_n D^n x = 0$$ where each $k_n$ is constant.
This implies that every LTI ODE is autonomous.  Are time-invariant and autonomous synonyms then? Is there an example of a (perhaps non-linear) ODE that is one but not the other?
Other questions discuss related issues for control theory, where there is a separate $u$ parameter to indicate the control choice; but my question is about pure ODEs.

No, because it's not necessary that the independent variable is time.

The definition of LTI that you have is a definition of an autonomous system. A more general one would be $\sum k_n D^n x = \sum c_mD^m u$, which is a non-autonomous LTI with the input $u$.
